# Delete row in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, delete-row

I have got this table:

```
Trader  Date        EUR
T1      01.05.2020. 12.36
T2      03.05.2020. 14.48
T2      02.05.2020. 23.69
T1      04.05.2020. 45.78
T3      04.05.2020. 15.26
```

After I apply pivot in Python by using pandas library:

```
a = a.pivot_table(index=['Date'],columns=['Trader'],values=['EUR'])
```

I got this view:

```
                                 EUR
    Trader         T1      T2     T3
      Date          
01.05.2020.     12.36     NaN    NaN
02.05.2020.       NaN   23.69    NaN
03.05.2020.       NaN   14.48    NaN
04.05.2020.     45.78     NaN  15.26
```

Now I would like to get rid of first row (EUR) and third row (Date) and use the rest later. In Excel I would simply delete both rows. How to do this in Python/panda?

Thanks

Valters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one element lists from your solution:

```
a = a.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Trader',values='EUR')
```

And then if need column from index `Date` then use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
a = (a.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Trader',values='EUR')
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
      .reset_index())
```

Comment: This syntax `a = a.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()` outputs error something like `TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`.`